# Expression Tree implementation issues

Tags: c++, data-structures, expression, binary-tree, arithmetic-expressions

I'm having a headache trying to build an expression tree, in particular the pointers for the treenodes, which i have no clue on how to implement and actually create the nodes to store data which is supposed to be pretty basic but the code just confuses me.

For example, when i want to create an expression of 5 + 5 this is what it should look like:

```
  +
 / \
5   5
```

However when implementing this, i'm not sure how to begin. How do i get the operator in the root node and the numbers as children? I know i can store them in a stack and read off the top however the set parent, left child and right child methods only take (TreeNode *) arguments while the vector tokens are type string.

Also the constructor for the TreeNode take an integer and operator value, why is that? How can i get those values into their respective nodes as root, parent and children?

```
ExprTree.cpp

    #include "ExprTree.h"
    #include <sstream>
    #include <iostream>

    TreeNode * createOperatorNode(const string & op){

      if (op == "+") return new TreeNode(Plus);
      if (op == "-") return new TreeNode(Minus);
      if (op == "*") return new TreeNode(Times);
      if (op == "/") return new TreeNode(Divide);
      return new TreeNode(NoOp);

    }

    /*
     * Basic constructor that sets up an empty Expr Tree.
     */
    ExprTree::ExprTree(){

        this->root = NULL;
       this-> _size = 0;

    }

    /*
     * Constructor that takes a TreeNode and sets up an ExprTree with that node at the root.
     */
    ExprTree::ExprTree(TreeNode * r){

        this->root = r;
    }

    ExprTree ExprTree::buildTree(vector<string> tokens){ 

// the tokens are the broken up arithimec expression
i.e 
5 
+ 
5
// not sure what to do here, i've tried using stacks but i wasn't sure how to get the stored data into the nodes.

    }
```

TreeNode.cpp

```
#include "TreeNode.h"

TreeNode::TreeNode(Operator o){
  op = o;
  parent = 0;
  leftChild = 0;
  rightChild = 0;
}

TreeNode::TreeNode(int val){
  op = Value;
  value = val;
  parent = 0;
  leftChild = 0;
  rightChild = 0;
}
```

TreeNode.h

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

enum Operator {Value, Plus, Minus, Times, Divide, NoOp};

class TreeNode {

 private:

  Operator op; //If this node represents an operator, this is where it's stored.
               //It can take values from the Operator enum (i.e. Plus, Minus, etc.)
               //If it represents a value, use the Value value. :D
  int value; //If this node stores an actual number, this is it.

  TreeNode * parent; //Pointer to the parent.
  TreeNode * leftChild; //Pointer to the left child of this node.
  TreeNode * rightChild; //Pointer to the right child of this node.

 public:

  TreeNode(Operator); //Constructor to use for +, -, * and /.
                      //Example: TreeNode(Plus);
  TreeNode(int); //Constructor to use for actual numbers.
                 //Example: TreeNode(5);
  void setParent(TreeNode *); //Set the parent pointer.
  void setLeftChild(TreeNode *); //Set the left child pointer.
  void setRightChild(TreeNode *); //Set the right child pointer.
  TreeNode * getParent(); //Get the parent pointer.
  TreeNode * getLeftChild(); //Get the left child pointer.
  TreeNode * getRightChild(); //Get the right child pointer.
  int getValue(); //Returns the stored value;
  Operator getOperator(); //Returns the stored operator.
  bool isValue(); //Returns true if this node is a Value node.
  bool isOperator(); //Returns truee if this node is Plus, Minus, Times or Divide node.
  std::string toString(); //Returns a simple string representation of the node.

};
```

Comment: Where is `ExprTree.h` ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way of parsing expressions is to build a recursive descent parser. This consists of mutually recursive functions called expression, term, and factor. A factor is the smallest unit, either a basic number or open parentheses, expression, close parentheses (so the mutual recursion comes in). Terms are collections of factors with multiplication and divide operators, and expressions are collections of terms joined by plus and minus operators.

You need a special rule for unary minus.

Now a recursive descent parser doesn't actually build a tree as a structure in memory. The tree is implicit in the call pattern. However if you want a tree you can easily enough modify it to build one.

It might help to take a look at my very simple Basic interpreter

https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/minibasic

Answer (score 0):

You simply use what TreeNode.h gives you.

For instance, if you want to create a tree with the name root that represents 5 + 5, you go like

```
TreeNode root(Plus);
root.setLeftChild(new TreeNode(5));
root.setRightChild(new TreeNode(5));
```

Within a parser, well, try to build one. Note that you can traverse your tree easily by following children and parent pointers.

Another way would be to create a constructor over a string, which evaluates as the outermost operator and then recursively constructs it's children by giving them the appropriate substrings, like

```
TreeNode::TreeNode(string expression){

    if(expression is number){
        create this as number node
    }
    create this as operator node with outermost operator
    split string by outermost operator
    set left child to left side of split string
    set right child to ...
}
```

That said, as a remark, I don't see `~TreeNode()` being defined, which means that you will have a memory leak.

Also, I recommend to separate Tree and TreeNode, that is to create a class Tree which has TreeNode as an inner class, and that the constructor and destructor of TreeNode is private (with Tree as a friend). Gives you more control over things. Actions such as setLeftChild can be dangerous in regard to memory leaks if done incorrectly and one would be able to create loops (which defies the idea of a tree).

Answer (score 0):

First, convert your expression into a postfix expression ([Infix To Postfix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772802/using-stacks-in-c-for-infix-and-postfix-expressions)).

**Expression :** `5 + 5`

**Postfix :**  `5 5 +`

Then parse the postfix string and whenever you find an operand push it into a stack, or if you find an operator then pop the two operands from the stack (if it's a binary operator) and then assign the tree root as the operator the left & right child as the operands.

```
Tree *t;
Stack<string> stack;

// parsing the tokens(expression)...
for(int i=0; i<token[i].length(); i++) {
    if(token[i] == "+" || token[i] == "-" || token[i] == "*" || token[i] == "/") {
        string op1 = stack.top(); stack.pop();
        string op2 = stack.top(); stack.pop();
        t->root = new createOperatorNode(token[i]);
        t->leftChild = new TreeNode(op1);
        t->rightChild = new TreeNode(op2);
    }
    else {
        stack.push(token[i]);
    }
}
```